# String with substrings in ascending order

Tags: combinatorics-on-words

Suppose you have several substrings, e.g.,

```
AEBCA
DEA
BDAEBAE
EDEBAE
AED
```

How would you create a minimal-length string that contains the substrings in order?

The context, real or contrived (don't know), was this: Suppose you have several trucks, each of which must be loaded with items in a specific order. The substrings are the loads for each truck, and the letters are the items.

The trucks load by queuing in front of a line of bins, with each bin having only items of like type. The trucks can move forward only. In what order should the bins be arranged to have the minimum number?

My solution (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1086058-counting-letters-in-strings.html) was to catenate the substrings (24 characters in this example), and then strike every letter that left the substrings ascending in the reduced string. That gave me the 11-character string below, and the substrings are repeated below it:

```
AEBDAEBAECA
    AEB  CA
   D    E A
  BDAEBAE  
 E D EBAE  
AE D
```

Is this an instance of a more general problem that I could research by name? Can anyone suggest a less naive algorithm that might generate a better result?

Thank you.

Comment: Would this question be more appropriate to stackoverflow? The nature of questions and answers I see here suggests I'm way out of my depth.

Comment: I can't understand how you got your 11-character string.  Could you provide more detail? (I don't have access to the linked Excel workbooks.)

Comment: Your 11-character string is not the shortest possible.  For example, one 10-character string is `AEBDCAEBAE` and another is `AEBCDAEBAE`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [shortest common supersequence](http://nist.gov/dads/HTML/shortestCommonSuperseq.html) (scs).  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem),

> For two input sequences, an scs can be formed from a longest common subsequence (lcs) easily.  For example, if $X[1..m]=abcbdab$ and $Y[1..n]=bdcaba$, the lcs is $Z[1..r]=bcba$.  By inserting the non-lcs symbols while preserving the symbol order, we get the scs: $U[1..t]=abdcabdab$.
>
> It is quite clear that $r+t=m+n$ for two input sequences.  However, for three or more input sequences this does not hold. Note also, that the lcs and the scs problems are not dual problems.
>
> For the more general problem of finding a string, $S$ which is a superstring of a set of strings $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_l$, the problem is NP-Complete.  Also, good approximations can be found for the average case but not for the worst case.

Comment: Thank you for giving my problem a name. The workbook is accessible at https://app.box.com/s/o3uxgpagcqjy34t7h5kcz0hf7ymkrbo4